# How do I style the scrollbar in Svelte?

Tags: scroll, scrollbar, svelte

I've been pulling my hair for hours trying to figure out how to restyle the default scrollbar in Svelte. I've tried regular HTML styles, tens of external `npm` packages, and every source I could find, but none of them worked. How can I restyle the default scrollbar in a Svelte website?

I've tried adding the following code to my stylesheet but to no avail:

```css
main::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0.25rem
}

main::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #1e1e24;
}

main::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    color: #93CAED
}
```

Comment: Svelte is not concerned with scrollbars - that's a browser-dependent thing. Just set a CSS rule in a stylesheet: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars

Comment: @Dai That's Firefox only. I meant a solution that's available for all web browsers. One solution I tried was `webkit-scrollbar`, but that didn't seem to work in Svelte in either.

Comment: Again, Svelte is not concerned with scrollbars - but yes, `scrollbar-width` and `scrollbar-color` only works in Firefox (but it is Standards-based), for Chrome, Edge and Safari you'll need to use `--webkit-scrollbar`). You haven't posted any code though so we can't really help you with specifics.

Comment: @Dai I've edited it with the code I've used.

Comment: Why are you applying `--webkit-scrollbar` styles to your `<main>` element when your `main` style rule doesn't stipulate that it's a scroll-container? Your root scroll container is either `<html>`  or `<body>`  so you should style those elements instead.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out Dai (from the original post's comments) was correct. I shouldn't have applied the styles on my `<main>` element. However, I didn't have much of a choice because the styles were to be applied to a `.svelte` file which only had 3 tags - `<script`, `<style`, and `<main>`. Fortunately, I found a way around this.

By prefixing the `::webkit-scrollbar` with `:root`, which automatically applies the styles in the block provided to the whole document.

Answer (score 0):

Please stop pulling out your hair, it won't help. But the following css would surely help you out to customize the scrollbar in Svelte.

For Webkit(ie. Chrome) browsers

```
:global(.main::-webkit-scrollbar) {
  width: 0.25rem
}

:global(.main::-webkit-scrollbar-track) {
  background: #1e1e24;
}

:global(.main::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb) {
  color: #93CAED
}
```

For Gecko(ie. Firefox) browsers

```
:global(.main){
  scrollbar-color: #93CAED #1e1e24;
  scrollbar-width: 0.25rem;
}
```

Assuming, "main" is the class name of the Html element where custom style of scrollbar will be applied.